# Select maximum across columns and identify column origin in R and/or ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several numeric columns in a data frame, I want to do the following:

1. Select maximum values across all the columns and return a column with the maximum values. This is easy.
2. The hard part: plot the returned column with different color segments identifying which column the part is from. For example, a red segment means those values are from column 1, a blue segment means from column 2.

A minimal example:

```
Olddata <- data.frame(X1=1:10,X2=5.5)
```

The returned data frame should be

```
Newdata <- data.frame(ColNew=c(rep(5.5,5),6,7,8,9,10)).
```

I am wondering how to plot Newdata as a line with the first part being red and the second part being blue. In addition, if this could be generalized to `Olddata <- data.frame(X1,X2,X3,...)`, so Newdata will be plotted as a line of a number of color segments.

Thanks!

Comment: See `which.max`. It's just as easy as part 1.

Comment: Or possibly `max.col` although it's for numerical matrices..

Comment: Add an example (showing what you already can do) if you want tested answers with code in them.

Comment: Thanks. I see that max.col identifies the column where the max values are from, but how could I **plot** the new column ColNew=max(Column1,Column2,...ColumnN) as a line with different color segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# since it's all numeric, let's make it a matrix
# matrices are easier to apply functions by row
old = as.matrix(Olddata)
newdata = data.frame(max.value  = apply(old, MARGIN = 1, FUN = max),
                     max.column = apply(old, MARGIN = 1, FUN = which.max))
# alternatively, you could do max.column = max.col(old)
newdata

> newdata
   max.value max.column
1        5.5          2
2        5.5          2
3        5.5          2
4        5.5          2
5        5.5          2
6        6.0          1
7        7.0          1
8        8.0          1
9        9.0          1
10      10.0          1
```

It's really not clear what you want the plot to look like. Here's a start with points (below).

```
with(newdata, plot(max.value, col = max.column))
```

Here's another guess with `ggplot`, this way won't do too well as-is if your max.column alternates back and forth (though adding in a little `rle` logic for the group aesthetic would fix that).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(newdata, aes(x = 1:nrow(newdata), y = max.value,
       group = max.column, color = factor(max.column))) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_bw()
```

Some questions for you to think about:

- If you connect all the points, what color do you want the segment joining 5.5 to 6?
- If you don't connect all the points, what do you want to do with points by themselves, like if `max. column` goes 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, what do do with the 2?
- I've assumed you just want row number on the x axis, is this right?

I think it makes the most sense for the scope of this particular question to be on the data extraction. **If you have trouble making the plot you want, you should specify it more completely in a new question.** You can link back to this question, use the same or slightly modified sample data, and use the method from my answer to get the data for plotting.

Comment: You answer and the plots are exactly what I need. I now believe I do not really need a line, points with different colors are perfectly fine so long as readers know which column those points are from using possibly a legend. Thanks!